# Youtube id from database row

Tags: php, regex, youtube

Ive been trying to extract the youtube id from the youtube url for long time and finally i found this code from another thread.

```
<?

    preg_match(
        '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mVck88W01I',
        $matches
    );


?>
```

and the id is will print when i write `echo $matches[1];` as it should

The problem is i want it to find the link from `$row[link]` in my database and when i replace the url with `echo "$row[link]";` it do not work. it only works with an youtube url?

and im 100% the `$row[link]` since im using it in other parts of the script and the link is being printed

My question is how can i make it print the youtube id for each row in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this. This can be easily accomplished using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
function getVideoID($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    list(,$id) = explode('=', $parts['query']);
    return $id;
}
```

Usage:

```
$link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mVck88W01I';
echo getVideoID($link);
```

Output:

```
0mVck88W01I
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/58053)

Comment: it works with the url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mVck88W01I

But it dosent work when i want it to print out my url from my mysql database using $row[link]